# How to set dashed axes on a box plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to figure out if it is possible using `pyplot` setting a dashed box (I mean the axes of plot contours) of the plot.

I know that could sound strange and horrible. but I would like to try using it.

Comment: You probably want to explain what a "dashed box of the plot" is.

Comment: I mean the axes of plot contours ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axes "box" consists of 4 "spines", which are accessible via `ax.spines`. You may set a linestyle to those as shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)

linestyles = ["--","-.",":", (0,(5,2,1,4))]

for ax, ls in zip(axes.flat, linestyles):
    for spine in ax.spines.values():
        spine.set_linestyle(ls)
        spine.set_linewidth(2)
    ax.set_title("linestyle: {}".format(ls))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]